# Python doesn't print sometimes

Tags: python, if-statement

So i wanna make a text adventure game but i can't explain this bug it simply doesn't print some parts i hope you guys can help me and explain this. My code is  below

```
print("Psst... hey you are finally awake")
print("You are currently in a empty room on a chair you got caught in your adventure by a wizard in his castle")
print("There are 3 doors in front of you")
print("If you open the first door you will enter in a room full of spikes")
print("But if you open the second door you will enter in a room full of lions who didn't eat a entire month")
print("And after the third door there is a room with deadly gas")
FirstChoice = input ("Wil you choose |1| |2| or |3| ")
if FirstChoice == "1":
    print("Wrong! Try again")
    SecondChance = input("Will you choose |1| |2| or |3| ")
elif SecondChance == "1":
    print("GAME OVER")
elif SecondChance == "2":
    print("You escaped!")
elif SecondChance == "3":
    print("GAME OVER")
elif FirstChoice == "2":
    print("You escaped!")
```

Comment: `SecondChance` is only defined in your first `if` block. In all the `elif` blocks, it is not defined, so it doesn't make sense to be trying to check its value. I think you've misunderstood how `if/elif/else` works.

Comment: What should happen if the first choice is 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
FirstChoice = input("Will you choose |1| |2| or |3|? ")
if FirstChoice != "2":
    print("Wrong! Try again")
    SecondChance = input("Will you choose |1| |2| or |3|? ")
    if SecondChance != "2":
        print("GAME OVER")
    else:
        print("You escaped!")
else:
    print("You escaped!")
```

You have to use a separate if statement for the second guess (It has to be nested within the first if statement). Also watch your indentation.